# Compute H-representation of a polytope after projection onto lower-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, computational-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

For a convex polytope described by many equalities and inequalities:
$P = \{(x,y): Ax + By \leq c, Dx+Ey = f\}$, can we get H-representation of the polytope $Q$ after projecting $P$ to x-space. In other words:
$Q = \{x: \exists~y:Ax + By \leq c, Dx+Ey = f \}$. I vaguely recall that I learnt some theorems claiming there exists a finitely many half spaces describing $Q$.

Consider a more general setting that matrix $E$ is not square and not full column/row rank.

Is this a well-studied problem (what is its name?) If we cannot get H-representation of $Q$ by simple linear algebra, I'm pretty sure we can do this numerically, any famous algorithms?

Comment: Weyl-Minkowski's Theorem says that very polytope is a polyhedron, which is the set of solutions of a finite system of linear inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fourier-Motzkin elimination (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination) for this task. The method is simple but slightly above linear algebra since it respect linear inequalities.

The method is exact and effective but not efficient as it may produces several redundant inequalities. Finding more efficient methods is still a topic of current research.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I went through some materials and found Fourier-Motzkin elimination very helpful. I'm wondering if there exists similar algorithms for non-linear optimization problems...

Comment: You are welcome. Such algorithm exist and are usually refered to as quantifier elimination. A nice algorithm which is very similar to FM-elimination is the Weispfenning-Loos elimination. I only used it for linear inequalties but as far as I remember it can also handle quadratic inequalities. A general-purpose method for polynomials is called cylindric algebraical decomposition. But details of this algorithm are beyond my knowledge.